# Case insensitive group_by in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

ok so i have this call

```
location.requests.group_by(&:song)
```

location is

```
>> location = Location.find 4
=> #<Location id: 4, venue: "Rod Laver Arena at Melbourne Park - Melbourne Vic, ...", 
showdate: "2010-11-20", created_at: "2010-10-28 01:20:42", updated_at: 
"2010-10-28 01:20:42", band_id: nil, artist_name: "Metallica">


location.requests.group_by(&:song)
```

this call is returning two records "One" and "one" because they are saved that way in the db....any idea on how to redo the group_by to only return one record with both

I am using sqlite

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Group_by can also take a code block. So instead of:

```
location.requests.group_by(&:song)
```

Do:

```
location.requests.group_by{|i| i.song.downcase}
```

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for pertinent documentation.